# jquery focus function is not working in iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios

I have a requirement like when we click an option from a dropdown, there is need to scroll to a textbox. To achvieve this, we are using focus function in jquery which is working fine in all android devices and even in Desktop ios also but not working in iphone 6. Please suggest any fix for this.

**dropdown html:**

```
<select data-val="true" data-val-required="X Field is required." id="bnkdtls-mthd1" name="FinancialInformation.PreferredUsdAccount" onchange="validateusd();" aria-required="true" aria-describedby="bnkdtls-mthd1-error" class="valid" aria-invalid="false"><option value="">CHOOSE A METHOD</option>
    <option value="2">USD Wire Transfer</option>
    <option value="3">USD Check to Address</option>
</select>
```

**jquery for change event**

```
$("#bankdtls").on('change', '#bnkdtls-mthd1', function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "") {
        DisableUSDSection();
        DisablePrizeMoneySection();
    }
    if ($(this).val() == "2") {
        //DisablePrizeMoneySection();
        EnableUSDSection();
        $(".usdbnknm input").focus();
    }
    if ($(this).val() == "3") {
        DisableUSDSection();
        $(".przemnymladrs input").focus()
    }

});
```

**target textbot html:**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 textbox1 paddinglftryt0 usdbnknm">
    <input class="textbox-input1 valid" id="FinancialInformation_UsdBankName" name="FinancialInformation.UsdBankName" onkeyup="validateUSDBankName();" type="text" value="bank" aria-invalid="false">
    <div class="valdtnerror-message" id="USDBankNamevaldtnID" style="display: none;">This field cannot be blank</div>
    <div class="valdtnerror-message" id="USDBankNamelenvaldtnID" style="display: none;">Bank Name cannot be more than 45 characters</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this Safari?

In terms of 'focusing' on a text input: I'm pretty certain iOS blocks this behaviour by default. You have to manually tap into the input then you get the `up/down` arrows in the top-left of the keyboard to navigate the form.

But, if the input is in a different location on-screen, you could navigate the screen to the correct 'area' it resides in like this:

```
//scroll to the 'top' position (minus 30 for a bit of padding) 
//   of a given input over 1s
$("html, body").animate({ 
    scrollTop: $(".przemnymladrs input").offset().top-30 
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Hi @scgough, thanks for ur reply. But need that input field to be focussed with the cursor in the respective textbox and keyboard should be pop-up.